# GCP - How to set Beta Permissions for setOrgPolicy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I run the following and get the error that I do not have permissions. How can I add permissions such that I can run `disable-enforce compute.disableNestedVirtualization`

```
user@cloudshell:~ (testproj)$ gcloud config set project testproj
Updated property [core/project].
user@cloudshell:~ (testproj)$ gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies disable-enforce compute.disableNestedVirtualization --project=testproj
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.resource-manager.org-policies.disable-enforce) User [user@mydomain.com] does not have permission to access project [testproj:setOrgPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

Comment: Do you have this role for your account: `roles/
orgpolicy.policyAdmin`

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation you need the Organization Policy Administrator role:

> To add a user as an Organization Policy Administrator, you must have
>   the [Organization
>   Administrator](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#adding_an_organization_admin)
>   role.
>   To set, change, or delete an organization policy, you must have the
>   [Organization Policy Administrator](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints#add-org-policy-admin) role.

```
1. gcloud organizations get-iam-policy ORGANIZATION_ID \
 --format json > iam.json
2. Use a text editor to add a new object to the `bindings` array in the iam.json file, that defines the group members and the role for those members
3. gcloud organizations set-iam-policy ORGANIZATION_ID iam.json
```

You can find [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints#override_the_organization_policy_for_a_project) how to override the organization policy for a project.

```
gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies disable-enforce BOOLEAN_CONSTRAINT --project PROJECT_ID
```